# Animate images with jQUery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm tring to learn how to do the effects, that this guy is using in his website.

I want to move image from left to right and vice versa.

How can I do it?

http://www.adhamdannaway.com/about

Comment: the simplest way to do something like that is to use CSS3 http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/

Comment: use this plugin its almost the same what you want : http://www.sequencejs.com/themes/apple-style/

Comment: Another good resource here: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions

Answer (score 0):

Read about jQuery animate function: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your HTML with the image tags are like this:

```
<img class="left-right" src="img-url.com"/>
<img class="right-left" src="img-url.com"/>
```

Your css for this would be like initially:

```
.left-right {
   position: absolute;
   left: -100px;
}

.right-left {
   position: absolute;
   right: -100px;
}
```

Just to make sure its not in the viewport we position it outside the boundaries of the frame.

Then using the jQuery animation we need to add an event:

```
$(".left-right").focus(function () {
    $(this).animate({left: "0px"}, 1000);
}); 


$(".right-left").focus(function () {
    $(this).animate({right: "0px"}, 1000);
});
```

Here the 1000 is 1000ms over which the element will animate from its -100px to 0px.

Comment: You can try a different event handler maybe. I've made a sample fiddle for you which would help. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7qFhp/).

This is dependent entirely on your css and how you've designed the layout of your page.

Answer (score 0):

100% animating code (this code will work to animate all image or div having class animation indivisually)

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".animation").mouseover(function(){
   $(this).animate({
                      height:'200px',
                      width:'200px',
                      left : '-11px'
                    })
                            });

$(".animation").mouseout(function(){
   $(this).animate({
                      height:'178px',
                      width:'178px',
                      left : '0px'
                    })
                            });

});
</script>
```